# Como configurar a permissão para testes no AndroidManifest?

Tags: android, testes, android-manifest

Estou com uma dúvida para dar a permissão pra realizar testes de em uma aplicação android.

Criei um caso de *test* mas ao rodar surge o seguinte no console:

> does not specify a android.test.InstrumentationTestRunner
>   instrumentation or does not declare uses-library android.test.runner
>   in its AndroidManifest.xml

Fui no arquivo `AndroidManifest.xml` da aplicação e introduzi o código:

```
<instrumentation android:name="android.test.InstrumentationTestRunner"
    android:targetPackage="com.voxar.cameraapp"
    android:label="your tests label" />
```

e coloquei:

`<uses-library android:name="android.test.runner" />`

Como sugerido no [stackoverflow.com](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1009970/android-eclipse-plugin-instrumentation-test-runner-not-specified)

Como solucionar os erros para que eu consiga começar a realizar os testes?

Answer (score 1):

@Daniel teoricamente é só adicionar no seu arquivo gradle essas dependencias.

`androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test:runner:0.3') {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
}
androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test:rules:0.3') {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
}`

Não precisa de permissão para executar um teste simples (trocar de tela). Se for acessar internet ou GPS ou Cartão SD, esse tipo de coisa, ai você precisa de permissão, caso contrário não precisa. Segue um link com instruções para você iniciar seus testes. Espero ter ajudado

http://developer.android.com/intl/pt-br/training/testing/index.html